# Will Heroku dyno daily restart affect multi-day sidekiq job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sidekiq

I have an app with long-running processes that transfer large amounts of data.  Some of these runs can take multiple days.

I'd love to be able to run these processes in a sidekiq job with a dedicated queue, but it's not clear from Heroku's docs if daily dyno restarts will interrupt the job.

Specifically [this page](https://www.heroku.com/dynos/lifecycle) mentions that dynos support graceful restarts to allow them to finish processing incoming requests.  Does that also apply to sidekiq workers that are still running a job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they will. What you should do is chunk your job and make it idempotent where it can resume.

The workers will receive `SIGINT` signal that you can listen for, depending on your job queue you are using. You will have 30 seconds from the time that signal is issued until it gets `SIGKILL` and you will not be able to gracefully shut down.

There is no way to avoid the 24 hour restart, but what some people I have heard do (if you're not able to shut down within 30 seconds) is every 6 hours or so, restart your own server programmatically so it only restarts at expected times.